# Google earth ee.data.authenticateViaPopup gets popup always blocked

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, google-api-js-client, outsystems

When I implement the example of google authentication for google earth Javascript API, I got the popup to sign in blocked and I got this message on the console:

Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.closed call.
Lv @ cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:406

I've tried to add the response headers:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', url);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy', 'same-origin-allow-popups');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
xhr.send();

var head1 = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

var meta1 = document.createElement('meta');
meta1.httpEquiv = 'Permissions-Policy';
meta1.content = 'ch-ua-form-factor=()';
head1.appendChild(meta1);
```

I added the permission policy because i got a warning about it.

This script has no effect.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

The popup was being closed because I was already logged in. The ee.data.authenticateViaOauth() is not working.

Comment: Add something like an working example to make it easier for other to follow your thoughts